# What's the difference between the Used and Redeemed states for Magento Enterprise gift cards?

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.14, gift-card

I'm trying to import some gift cards from an old community module, but I'm not sure what the difference is between the Used and Redeemed states in Magento EE 1.14 gift card accounts. Anyone got any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used means an order was placed and the gift card code was entered to get a discount.
redeemed means that the gift card was transformed into store credit.